# Understanding C++03 Standard Grammar for Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++03

The standard C++03 grammar for overloading an operator is as follows:

*operator-function-id*:
  **operator** *operator*
  **operator** *operator* < *template-argument-list*?>

The first one is the ordinary operator overloading syntax that we normally use, e.g.

```
Myclass operator + (Myclass s) {...}
```

But what does the second alternative mean? In particular, under what situation do we use the *template-argument-list*? After a quick look at C++11, I found that the second form was removed from the standard. What was the original intention of it?

EDIT: after testing with VC++2010, below is one way of using the above syntax, although it does not make much sense to me:

```
class K {
public:
    int a;
    template <int B>
    int operator + (int b) {
        return a+b+B;
    }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    K k;
    k.a=1;
    int s;
    s=k.operator+<115>(2);
    printf("%d\n",s);
    return 0;

}

output:118
```

Comment: What are "templated operators"?

Comment: You can overload operators for your class. And those overloads can be template functions.

Comment: @StoryTeller but explicit specializations can't be in class scope.

Comment: @GillBates There's always specializations as free functions.

Comment: @StoryTeller Fair enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grammar rule which allows specialization of operator function templates still exists in C++11, it's just in a different place.

**[temp.names]/1 (C++03)**:

> A template specialization (14.7) can be referred to by a template-id:
>
> template-id:
>
> ```
> template-name < template-argument-listopt>
> ```
>
> template-name:
>
> ```
> identifier
> ```
>
> template-argument-list:
>
> ```
> template-argument
> template-argument-list , template-argument
> ```
>
> template-argument:
>
> ```
> assignment-expression
> type-id
> id-expression
> ```

**[temp.names]/1 (C++11)**:

> A template specialization (14.7) can be referred to by a template-id:
>
> simple-template-id:
>
> ```
> template-name < template-argument-listopt>
> ```
>
> template-id:
>
> ```
> simple-template-id
> operator-function-id < template-argument-listopt> <- HERE
> literal-operator-id < template-argument-listopt>
> ```
>
> template-name:
>
> ```
> identifer
> ```
>
> template-argument-list:
>
> ```
> template-argument ...opt
> template-argument-list , template-argument ...opt
> ```
>
> template-argument:
>
> ```
> constant-expression
> type-id
> id-expression
> ```

This was likely done because the grammatical rule *operator-function-id* is referred to in contexts where that template argument list would not make sense, so they moved the rule to somewhere more reasonable </conjecture>.

---

Here is an example of this rule in action:

```
struct foo{
    template <typename T>
    void operator() (T t) { std::cout << t; }
};

template <>
void foo::operator()<double> (double) { 
    std::cout << "It's a double!"; 
}
```

Note the specialization for `operator()` for when `T` is `double`. If you run this code:

```
foo f;
f(0);
f(0.0);
```

Then `0` will be printed for the first call, and `It's a double!` for the second.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edfe39e14dbc2e9e)

Comment: That makes more sense than flat out removing it, come to think of it :)

Comment: See [core issue 301](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#301).